# How to make rp2040 DynPin usable for Adc with OnesShot read

Tags: rust, type-conversion, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I am trying to convert from a type erased type to a value type.
I have the following struct that accepts `DynPin` , which is the [type erased type of a rp2040 gpio](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/0.4.0/rp2040_hal/gpio/dynpin/index.html#) pin.

```
pub struct PhProbe{
  analog_read_pin: DynPin,
}
```

Now using the [rp2040 analog to digital converter](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/adc/index.html) with [OneShot](https://docs.rs/embedded-hal/0.2.3/embedded_hal/adc/trait.OneShot.html) I want to use this pin in the read function (ignore return value). But the [read function](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/src/rp2040_hal/adc.rs.html#134) of the ADC only accepts pins that implement `Channel<ADC>` which is done using a [macro](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/src/rp2040_hal/adc.rs.html#97), which as you can see is only implemented for the specific gpios 26-29.

```
pub fn read(&mut self, adc: Adc) {
      let reading: u16 = adc.read(&mut <DynPin as Into<FloatingInput>>::into(self.analog_read_pin)).unwrap();
    }
```

The pin is created using the `into_floating_input()` function and handed to the `PhProbe::new()` function by making a `DynPin` using `into()`.

```
let ph_pin = pins.gpio26.into_floating_input();
let ph_meter = PhProbe::new(ph_pin.into());
```

I was trying to make a analog input pin (FloatingInput) out of the DynPin, but this doesn't satisfy the bounds `Channel<Adc>` of `OneShot`. Is there a a way to use any of the gpio26-29 pins with this or do I need to specify `Gpio26` for this?